# size_t cast in getline in C

Tags: c, getline, size-t

I just found out that gets is deprecated and scanf is not recommended because of reliability problems, so I am trying out getline().

I can use getline without problems if i declare a size_t variable and assign it  the number of bytes to use.

I understand that if i want getline to memalloc for me I have to asign the second parameter (the size_t * one) to zero and the char ** to NULL. And it works:

```
int main(){
    int read;
    size_t zero = 0;
    char *A;
    A=NULL;
    printf("Write something:\n");
    read=getline(&A, &zero, stdin);
    if(read!= -1) puts(A);
    return 0;
}
```

It works if I assign zero to the variable, but why not can I just not declare the variable and  cast a zero (0) like this:

```
int main(){
    int read;
    //size_t zero = 0;
    char *A;
    A=NULL;
    printf("Write something:\n");
    read=getline(&A, (size_t *)0, stdin);
    if(read!= -1) puts(A);
    return 0;
}
```

The last code compile fine, but getline returns -1, so an error.

Comment: the max length your using (in the good version) is 0, so no character(s) will be read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `&size` is not a null pointer. It is the valid address of an object *containing* `0`, which is different from the pointer being `0` and pointing nowhere.

BTW, `gets` was removed from the C standard but `fgets` wasn't. This is the way to go for portable C.

Answer (score 0):

```
this is the correct way to use getline()

#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int bytes_read;   // number of bytes actually read
    int nbytes = 100; // max number of bytes to read
    char *my_string;  // ptr to byte read

    puts ("Please enter a line of text.");

    /* These 2 lines are the heart of the program. */
    my_string = (char *) malloc (nbytes + 1);
    if( NULL == my_string )
    { // then error occurred with malloc
        perror( "malloc" );
        exit(1);
    }

    // implied else

    bytes_read = getline (&my_string, &nbytes, stdin);

    if (bytes_read == -1)
    {
        puts ("ERROR!");
    }
    else
    {
        puts ("You typed:");
        puts (my_string);
    }

    free( my_string );
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at the [manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getline) of `getline()` to get a better understanding.

As the function prototye says

`ssize_t getline(char **lineptr, size_t *n, FILE *stream);`

There are two cases.

1. **If the `*lineptr` is `NULL`**, then `getline()` itself will allocate a buffer for storing the line, which needs to be freed by the user. In this case, as `*lineptr` is  `NULL`, there is no significance of the size of the buffer (denoted by `size_t *n`) and its ignored. `getline()` handles alloction of memory.
2. **If before calling `getline()`, `*lineptr` contains a pointer to a `malloc()`-allocated buffer** , then we need to tell the size of the buffer to `getline()`, that is `*n` bytes in size. In case, if the buffer is not large enough to hold the line, `getline()` resizes it with `realloc()`, updating `*lineptr` and `*n` with new values.

So, as per your question

> I can use getline without problems if i declare a size_t variable and assign it the number of bytes to use.

==> `Number of bytes to use` should be the the size of allocated buffer (if allocated).

> I understand that if i want getline to memalloc for me I have to asign the second parameter (the size_t * one) to zero and the char ** to NULL.

==> `*lineptr` should be NULL, right. `*n` can be holding any value as it will be ignored, but `n` should be a vaild pointer [as in case of `size_t zero = 0;` and `&zero`], not a `NULL` pointer [as in case of `(size_t *)0`], because, after a successful call to `getptr()`, the `*n` will be updated to reflect the allocated size.

Hope this helps!!